# Running a pip-installed Spyder in virtual environment on Ubuntu without Anaconda?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ide, virtualenv, spyder

I just recently started learning Ubuntu (17.04) and have managed to figure out how get plain Python3.5 + Spyder3 running, have created a virtual environment, and gotten the v-env running with Spyder by changing the interpreter setting within Spyder via pointing it to the virtual environment bin.

However, I saw numerous other ways of installing Spyder, primarily via a pip3 install in the environment itself, but I found nothing as to how to actually RUN the pip-installed Spyder. Running "Spyder3" always runs the default install regardless of location.

Does anyone know how to actually run it?

I was curious because I figured it would allow for a similar functionality that Anaconda provides where you can simply select your virtual environment and run the respective Spyder version for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Seems that I was somehow running it from the wrong location, just had to run Spyder3 from the v-env bin folder.

Comment: Super late to comment, but as someone that prefers to run Spyder without having to install Anaconda and is a "new" user to Linux, this answer was perfect for my needs.

Comment: And as a late thank you to your comment - THANK YOU.  This is exactly what I wanted to do to aboid conda / spyder messing with my system installation.